# Use full .NET Framework with existing ASP.NET Core project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core web application currently running on .NET Core, which now needs to reference internal libraries which were built for and will only run on the full .NET Framework.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-asp-net-core):

> ASP.NET Core apps can run on .NET Core or on the full .NET Framework.

...What steps are needed to change an existing ASP.NET Core project to run on the full .NET Framework?

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation or in the Visual Studio tooling to switch between .NET Core and the full .NET Framework.

Comment: Do you need to change the project type from core to full .net, or is it only about having a reference from .NET Core to the full framework assembly?

Comment: @JakubSzumiato - just the reference, the runtime framework. I want to keep the new project structure for ASP.NET Core, and take advantage of the 'unified story for building web UI and web APIs', amongst the other advantages ASP.NET Core gives us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be enough to change your project.json by removing the `netcoreapp1.0` section inside `frameworks` and replacing it with `net4xy`, where x and y depend on the version of .Net Framework you want to target, e.g. `net461` for .Net 4.6.1.

For example, before:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.1"
      }
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
```

After:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have to pick up a right project type when defining this ASP.NET Core application. When selecting the project type, you can choose if you want to have .NET Core that runs everywhere, or .NET Core that runs on .NET Framework (you select the version from the drop down list on the top-left of the dialog).

Those should be a different options in your new project dialog.

This way, in your references (project.json) you will see only .NET Framework of selected version and framework dependencies which you choose (you normally add the .NET Framework reference as for any other project type).

There's a lot going on in this topic as project.json is being abandoned by Microsoft on favour of MSBuild xml files.

There's also a nice post of Scott Hanselman about this topic here:http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx

Please also note, that if you want to run a .NET Core application that runs anywhere, you can't reference full .NET Framework libraries (only .NET Standard).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was really looking to do this without re-creating the project. Scott's blog post was an interesting read however and it will be good to see how the tooling improves around these scenarios.